# Vector having same absolute correlation with all columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

Let $\mathbf{\Phi}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a real valued matrix with $m\le n$.

> I want to find a vector $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\frac{\left|\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{\phi}_i\rangle\right|}{\|\mathbf{\phi}_i\|}=c$ for some constant $c$ for all $i=1,\cdots, n$, where $\mathbf{\phi}_i,\ i=1,\cdots, n$ are the columns of $\mathbf{\Phi}.$ However, I do not want $\frac{\langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{\phi}_i\rangle\mathbf{\phi}_i} {\|\mathbf{\phi}_i\|^2}$ to be constant for all $i$.

Note that if $\mathbf{\phi}_i$ are all orthonormal, then such a vector is $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{\Phi 1}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, I don't know where to start for the general case. Does anyone have any idea or maybe some pointers to relevant literature? I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** This is a special case of a general question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741513/is-there-a-vector-y-such-that-p-sy-is-constant-for-all-sets-s-of-size) which also, sadly, remains unanswered.

Comment: Yes, that case demands $m=n$, I have edited the question. I wanted to mean that for this special case of $m=n$ things are simple but I don't know how to proceed if $m<n$.

Comment: I encountered some problems when trying to do a reduction, but I suspect that it's NP-hard by reduction to some variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem. Let's the first $m$ vectors be the basis and then for $m+1$-th vector we have $\langle v_{m+1}, y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i \langle v_i, y \rangle$. To get $c$, you need to know the signs of $\langle v_i, y \rangle$, i.e. to select a sign for each $\alpha_i$ to get sum $c$. The direct reduction didn't work though (because the desired sum is not arbitrary), and I didn't quickly find a variation which works.